# Converting vb.net to old visual basic 6.0 code

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I convert the code from c# to vb.net. now i need to convert the code to Visual Basic 6.0

Anyone can give a little hand on this conversion please?

```
Private Shared Function DigitoM10(ByVal pIntNumero As Long, ByVal pIntPersonaliza As Integer) As Integer
    Dim intPesos = {2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1}
    Dim strText = pIntNumero.ToString
    If strText.Length > 16 Then Throw New Exception("Número no soportado para cálculo del dígito verificador")
    Dim intSuma = 0
    Dim intIdx = 0

    For intPos = strText.Length - 1 To 0
        intSuma += Convert.ToInt32(strText(intPos).ToString) * intPesos(intIdx)
        intIdx += 1
    Next

    intSuma = intSuma Mod 10
    intSuma = 10 - intSuma

    If intSuma = 10 Then
        intSuma = 3
    End If

    Return intSuma + pIntPersonaliza
End Function
```

Comment: Can I ask why do you need to do such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it will be in a module, you can drop the `Shared` keyword.

```
Public Function DigitoM10(ByVal pIntNumero As Double, ByVal pIntPersonaliza As Long) As Long
    Dim intPesos As Variant
    Dim strText As String
    Dim intSuma As Long, intIdx As Long, intPos As Long

    intPesos = Array(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1)
    strText = Format$(pIntNumero, "0")
    If Len(strText) > 16 Then
        Err.Raise ErrorValueEnum.adErrInvalidArgument, "DigitoM10", "Número no soportado para cálculo del dígito verificador"
    End If

    intSuma = 0
    intIdx = LBound(intPesos)

    For intPos = Len(strText) To 1 Step -1
        intSuma = intSuma + CLng(Mid$(strText, intPos, 1)) * intPesos(intIdx)
        intIdx = intIdx + 1
    Next

    intSuma = intSuma Mod 10
    intSuma = 10 - intSuma

    If intSuma = 10 Then
        intSuma = 3
    End If

    DigitoM10 = intSuma + pIntPersonaliza
End Function
```

I had to change a lot of things. The dot notation as in `strText.Length` is often not supported in VB6. Use `Len(strText)` instead. Throwing an exception is done with `Err.Raise`.

Note that `Long` in .NET is a 64-bit integer, and not available in VB6. A .NET `Integer` is a VB6 `Long`. So I declared `pIntNumero As Double` and formatted it with `Format$(pIntNumero, "0")` to convert it into a string, otherwise, with `CStr()`, it might switch to an exponential format. This works until 15 digits. If you need 16 digits, supply the number directly as string instead

```
Public Function DigitoM10(ByVal strText As String, ByVal pIntPersonaliza As Long) As Long
```

Then you can drop the line

```
strText = Format$(pIntNumero, "0")
```

In .NET strings can be indexed to retrieve single characters as in `strText(intPos)`. This is done with the `Mid$` function in VB6.

Note also that in .NET, arrays are always zero based. I.e., the first index is `0`. In VB6/VBA they are often 1-based, but this can be changed. See: [Option Base statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-base-statement) and [Declaring arrays (VBA)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-arrays). Note that VB6 and VBA are the same language operating in different environments.

Test this method with known examples!

Comment: Note that the VB6 editor does not support Unicode, so the `Número` etc will only be interpreted correctly if the locale for non-Unicode programs on the current computer is compatible with the locale under which it was written. `ChrW$` should be used to work around this. I would also use the [`Decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/decimal-data-type) type as a replacement for the 64-bit `Long`. It needs to be declared as `Variant`, so there must be a `VarType` check too.